# Unwanted KEY column while moving code from thrift to CQL

Tags: cassandra, thrift, cql, datastax-enterprise, cqlsh

We are running Datastax Enterprise 4.8.8 
We have multiple applications connecting to Cassandra using Hector APIs(Thrift Communication).

As a part of moving from Thrift communication to CQL Communication(using Datastax Cassandra Drivers): I see a strange error: an extra KEY column is added in my ColumnFamily schema.

ColumnFamily was created long time back using `cassandra-cli`:

```
  CREATE TABLE mykeyspace."ColumnFamilyName" (
        key blob,
        column1 text,
        value blob,
        PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
    ) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND comment = ''
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = 'NONE'
    AND caching = {
        'keys' : 'ALL',
        'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'
    }
    AND compression = {
        'chunk_length_kb' : 64,
        'sstable_compression' : 'LZ4Compressor'
    }
    AND compaction = {
        'class' : 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy',
        'min_sstable_size' : 52428800
    };
```

Above is correct & expected schema copied from DevCenter. Same ColumnFamily I f a try to see schema from cqlsh, I see below:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> DESC mykeyspace."ColumnFamilyName";

/*
Warning: Table mykeyspace."ColumnFamilyName" omitted because it has 
constructs not compatible with CQL (was created via legacy API).
```

Approximate structure, for reference:
(this should not be used to reproduce this schema)

```
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace."ColumnFamilyName" (
    key blob,
    column1 text,
    value blob,
    "KEY" blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 ASC)
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_sstable_size': '52428800', 
       'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_kb': '64', 
       'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = 'NONE';
*/
```

Did anyone had this type of issue? If yes any suggested solution without recreation of the table? Extra KEY column is visible only through CQLSH & not from Devcenter UI.

Last thing, I am even not able to run COPY command because of this extra KEY column(as this is a part of partition key).

Comment: Datastax Recommended to do a minor upgrade of DSE 4.8.8 to 4.8.15. Even After the problem is not fixed yet. No permanent solution we can see for this. Only Table recreations & REstore Data in new tables is the only option across whole cluster. We have written Scripts to do this. If anyone faced similar thing, please reply??